# Microsoft SQL Server vNext – Linux edition - what SQL Server features does it lack?

Tags: sql-server, linux, ubuntu, vnext

I have a project where the choice of database engine is still up in the air, based on affordability and feature-set. Some basic groundwork has been carried out using SQL Server, and in evaluating the cost implications of opting to adopt SQL Server, versus a different vendor's product, I noticed that Microsoft has just released their [public preview of SQL Server v.Next](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-vnext-including-Linux), which allows one to run SQL Server on a Linux platform.

According to [www.theregister.co.uk](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2016/11/18/microsoft_running_windows_apps_on_linux/), the public preview is a SQL Server executable that runs on *nix-based systems by utilising Drawbridge, which is essentially a way of running Windows applications on a tiny version of the Windows 8 kernel, run inside a sandbox.

One issue most open source advocates have had with Microsoft's SQL Server is that SQL Server Enterprise contains all functionality, and when opting for a more budget-friendly version, certain limitations are imposed on you.

Specifically, Standard Edition and Web Edition impose upper limits on in-memory column store (32GB and 16GB respectively), and Web Edition removes backup compression as a feature.

I've searched the web in an attempt to find out how Microsoft intends to license SQL Server as far as Linux versions are concerned, my main concern being related to database mirroring. As far as database mirroring is concerned, SQL Server Standard and SQL Server Web Editions both have a subset of the functionality provided by SQL Server Enterprise.

I'm looking to understand three things:

- How is Microsoft going to license SQL Server vNext for Linux (specifically, the Ubuntu version)?
- If vNext is a subset of the functionality of the Windows version of SQL Server, what functionality is omitted?
- Is database mirroring functionality present in the Linux distros of SQL Server vNext?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think licensing information has been released yet.

What we do know is SQL Server Next on Windows & Linux will run a single feature set.  Here is a quote taken from [MS at Connect()](http://www.zdnet.com/article/microsofts-sql-server-next-for-linux-windows-hit-public-preview/).

> Microsoft officials said SQL Server Next on Linux and SQL Server Next
>   on Windows are based on a single code base. "There are some features
>   that have platform specific characteristics. For example, file paths
>   in Linux are different than file paths in Windows," said a
>   spokesperson. But they are not two completely different products.

My take on this is: SQL Server 2018 (or whatever it ends up being called) will be the same on Linux and Windows.  This lines up with the big news about [SQL Server 2016 Service Pack 1](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#tbm=nws&q=sql+server+2016+sp1).  MS have announced all editions will be functionally the same, from LocalDb to Enterprise.

While the Linux version remains in preview it is hard be sure what the final product will look like.  If this is choice you have to make soon you may well feel the Linux solution isn't, quite, ready for prime-time.

Comment: Some more info on SQL Server vNext, taken form [The Register](https://apple.news/A17raPQpxPCOhyLxthHJhmA). Seems to confirm licensing will match Windows. Also highlights a few features that haven't been ported, yet.

Comment: The vNext engine is supposed to be same on Windows and Linux, however SSAS, SSRS, & SSIS are still missing on Linux. I'm not sure if SSRS even ever make it. Being said, why do we have to pay more for the less?